# how do you implement System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOder and NetworkToHostOrder

Tags: c#

The `HostToNetworkOrder` method converts multibyte integer values stored on the host system from the byte order used by the host to the byte order used by the network, and the `NetworkToHostOrder` does the reverse.

Question is how to implement these methods in C#, assuming that it is not available in the system library.

Comment: What have you tried?  I suggest you research how the function works, try working with it a bit and make sure you understand it, then take a shot at implementing it.  Once you get stuck, come back and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

.NET is open source since November 2014, so you can simply copy the classes from here:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs

The official `HostToNetworkOrder` implementation is:

```
        public static long HostToNetworkOrder(long host) {
#if BIGENDIAN
            return host;
#else
            return (((long)HostToNetworkOrder((int)host) & 0xFFFFFFFF) << 32)
                    | ((long)HostToNetworkOrder((int)(host >> 32)) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
#endif
        }
```

@brunolemos

Answer (score -1):

> how to implement these methods in C#, assuming that it is not available in the system library.

It is available, so don't re-implement it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.networktohostorder.aspx

Comment: They are not available when programming for Win8 Store Apps, for example.

Comment: Point taken. However I refer to my first comment on the op: what have you tried? Detecting system byte order then constructing a bit shift+mask algorithm is near trivial, and can be solved with a Google search. It also isn't C# specific (except the detection of system byte order, which is CLR specific)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx shows how to do this on platforms where the networktohostorder API isn't available.